# Pass Parameters to Python Script from Web App?

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4

I have a python file that takes in 6 parameters from the command line and runs.

```
python_file.py param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6
```

What I would like to do is pass the parameters from a web app using flask with bootstrap.  Each parameter needs to have the option from the front end to select what parameter the user chooses.  Example of what I am looking for on the front end below is:

```
Param1_drop_down:  Param2 drop_down:
- option1          - option1 etc..
- option2
- option3
- option4
```

Any ideas on this?  I am new to front end work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it how to create a web app with dropdown options? Or do you already have that web app and you wonder how to send data from it to a Flask server that would pass them to your Python file?

Comment: @AlexanderRossa it is really both of those.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the command line to receive the args, I recommend the usage of  `subprocess.Popen`, with that you can run your script in the same way, Popen expects you to run a bash command, you can easily use it to execute your python file with the args chosen by the users.

edit to be more clear:
Lets say you have this python script.

```
from time import sleep
count = 0
while True:
    print("Hello", count)
    count += 1
    sleep(10)
```

And you want to call it from another script, you can use `subprocess.Popen` to do this for you.

i.e

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["python3","yourfile.py"])

#Do something more while the other process is running
```

You can also redirect the Popen output to a variable and do some work with the return of your code.

Comment: what if I just need the parameters to be passed straight to the python file without using the command line?  Is that what you are saying this option does?

Comment: I've added more information on my answer. Yes, it will run as a command line, but it will be runned directly from your code, so, you can manipulate which args you want to use.